# "Tell me why you being (or be) interested in pursuing a career as an accountant?"

Tags: reasoning, transcription

I am listening to an audio recording about business English on BBC.

I hear a question at 12m:10s.

[12:10](http://http-ws.bbc.co.uk.edgesuite.net/mp3/ukchina/simp/2010/03/bbc_bc_challenge_interviews_au_bb.mp3)

It sounds like

> Tell me why you being (or be) interested in pursuing a career as an accountant?""

I would like to know what the correct word he used...

I know in some situation "being" is used for "reasoning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tell me why you'd (you would) be interested in pursuing a career as an accountant.

This is a modal meaning of "would" that indicates determination or intention. It has no essential difference in meaning to:

> Tell me why you are interested in pursuing a career as an accountant.

Comment: Is it possible to rephrase the question with the word "being"? Or is it possible to use the word "being" to answer this question? like, "of course, being an accountant, I ...".

Comment: @StatsCruncher If you reply "Being an accountant, I..." I would assume you are an accountant already, instead of applying to be one. As for the question, "Tell me why you are interested in being an accountant." means the same.

Comment: Wow, your explanation is clear. So wonderful. Thanks.

Comment: @StatsCruncher yes, and yes: Q: "Why are you interested in being an accountant?" A: "Being an accountant has many perks.  Being an accountant pays well.  Being an accountant means I get to sit in air conditioning."

Comment: @JustinStafford Thank your for supplementing Q&A in detail.